# I thought interfaces couldn't be instantiated in java

Tags: java, jpa

I'm working on some JPA stuff and i'm a little confused with some of the start up code that you have to write.

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
```

Those three variables all have an interface as their type. How can we do things like

```
manager.persist()
transaction.commit()
```

etc if interfaces cannot be instantiated?

Answer (score 2):

Interface cannot be instantiated but an interface reference can hold an object of any class implementing that interface. So in your case

```
EntityManagerFactory factory
```

is a reference of interface which is holding an object of the class implenting it , returned by :

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
```

and hence this statement becomes correct:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Interfaces can not be instantiated but they provide a contract to call methods on objects that implement the interfaces.

So when you for example take a look at the `EntityManager`, `factory.createEntityManager()` is returning an object that implements the interface `EntityManager`. Interfaces make sure that the returned object provides certain required methods.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it can be a _very different_ type. It _will_ be an implementation class, but that class _will_ implement `EntityManager`

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is confusing to say it like that.

Comment: So is this similar to how `List` is an interface but `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` can be pointed to by a variable of type `List` ?

Comment: Yes, LinkedList and ArrayList are concrete implementations of the List interface.

Comment: So how can i see which objects that implement those interfaces are being returned? So i can see how they implement the methods that the interface defines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstand what happened here.

```
  EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager(); // here manager is only a reference You are getting that from EntityManagerFactory.
```

Now Factory class returns the manager type object. **There is no instantiating for interfaces in Java**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better seen than expained.

Examples:

```
public class AttackCommand implements Command {}...
public class DefendCommand implements Command {}...
....
```

let's say we wanted to add these to a common list of commands. Then you could add these to the list below.

(in a new class)

```
public ArrayList<Command> commands = new ArrayList();

public CommandManager() {
    commands.add(new AttackCommand());
    commands.add(new DefendCommand());
}
```

Now here is where that supposed reference comes in. What if we wanted to get a list of the command by name (pretending command has a getName method), or the last attacked target via AttackCommand (pretending it has a LastAttacked method)?.

```
public void printNames() {
    for (Command cmd : commands) {
        System.out.println(cmd.getName());
    }
}

public Entity getLastAttackTarget() {
    for (Command cmd : commands) {
        if (cmd instanceof AttackCommand) {
            return cmd.lastAttacked();
        }
    }
}
```

(I know that a map of the commands to just grab by name would be better, but for the sake of the example....)

In essence, it's a better general reference to all things that inherit the interface, but not the interface itself.